# Swift Uicollection view inside a table View

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

I got an image url array inside a post object array I want to display this post array in a table view and display the images as a collection view inside  the table view. How can I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRnHg.png)do it? I tired to use a int i as an indicator but it doesn't work.

here are the codes

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.postsText.text = postLists[indexPath.row].postText
    i = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (postLists[i].imageUrlList?.count)!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionCell
        let url =  postLists[i].imageUrlList![indexPath.row]
            let imgUrl = URL(string: url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imgUrl!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    // if download hits an error, so lets return out
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                // if there is no error happens...
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { // in half a second...
                    cell.postPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }).resume()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: refere this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxEGlpeONOc

Comment: check your array data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forcefully wrap optional ever Until you are very sure. (I can comment also but I want to add more details which is not suitable for comment so forgive )

Another thing I can see is use `indexPath.item` in `collectionView` not `indexPath.row` both will be same but this is standard I always follows.

You are not calling `URLSession.data` task in background thread. it is always recommend to do so. my suggestion is to that you should  use some third party library like **SDWebIamge**  which will helpful to you cache already downloaded image.

**Wy Crash**:

What I am seeing is Crash because of your variable `i` in your code `postLists[i].`

**What you should do**

Inside

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

you can set tag to your collection view like

```
cell.yourCollectionViewObject.tag = indexPath.row
```

and replace

```
    let url =  postLists[i].imageUrlList![indexPath.row]
```

with

```
    let url =  postLists[collectionView.tag].imageUrlList![indexPath.row]
```

Hope it is helpful